# Why so many scanned Objects?

Tags: mongodb, spatial, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with the following objects:

```js
> db.shapes.find()
{ "_id" : "P1", "amenity" : "restaurant", "shape" : { "type" : "Point", 
"coordinates" : [ 2, 2 ] } }
{ "_id" : "P2", "amenity" : "restaurant", "shape" : { "type" : "Point", 
"coordinates" : [ 2, 4 ] } }
{ "_id" : "P3", "amenity" : "police", "shape" : { "type" : "Point", 
"coordinates" : [ 4, 2 ] } }
{ "_id" : "P4", "amenity" : "police", "shape" : { "type" : "Point", 
"coordinates" : [ 4, 4 ] } }
```

The explain() on the following query gives a strange (in my opinion) result:

```js
> db.shapes.find({shape:{$nearSphere:{$geometry:{type: "Point", coordinates: 
 [0,0]}}}}, {id:1, amenity:1}).limit(2).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 22,
        "nscanned" : 22,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 22,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 22,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 1,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "server" : "DBTest:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

Why there are this much objects scanned ? I mean, the table only has 4 
objects and mongodb scans 22 ?

I am thankful for any explanation.

Bye, Andre

---

```js
> db.shapes.find({shape:{$nearSphere:{$geometry:{type: "Point", coordinates:
...  [0,0]}}}}, {id:1, amenity:1}).limit(2).explain(1)
{
        "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 22,
        "nscanned" : 22,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 22,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 22,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 1,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "allPlans" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 22,
                        "nscanned" : 22,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {

                        }
                }
        ],
        "server" : "DBTest:27017",
        "filterSet" : false,
        "stats" : {
                "type" : "LIMIT",
                "works" : 22,
                "yields" : 0,
                "unyields" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 20,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "children" : [
                        {
                                "type" : "PROJECTION",
                                "works" : 22,
                                "yields" : 0,
                                "unyields" : 0,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 2,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                "children" : [
                                        {
                                                "type" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
                                                "works" : 22,
                                                "yields" : 0,
                                                "unyields" : 0,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "advanced" : 2,
                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                                "children" : [ ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put a $maxDistance value in, as a matter of interest. I take it you have a 2dsphere index on the shape field?

Comment: Yes, there is a 2dsphere-Index on the shape field.

Comment: And what does $maxDistance do if you add to query?

Comment: show explain({ verbose: true }) please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using version 2.4 and are running into https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12231 which was fixed for version 2.6.  If you upgrade, it's likely you will no longer see the bogus nscanned numbers in explain() output.